# Webservice Response is turned into ref parameter when using MessageContract

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, messagecontract

I have defined the following Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHealthProducts
{
    [OperationContract()]
    ResponseClass OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate();
}
```

Which returns the following type

```
[MessageContract]
public class ResponseClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string AnimalSpeciesCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int VBN
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I expected that the generated client code would expose the OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate method in the following way:

```
HealthProductsClient client = new HealthProductsClient();
ResponseClass response = client.OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate();
```

Instead, the properties of *ResponseClass* aren't wrapped in the ResponseClass, but exposed like so:

```
string OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate(out int VBN)
```

When I exchange the MessageContract for a DataContract attribute and the MessageBodyMember for a DataMember attribute, I get the expected behaviour (ResponseClass response type).
I need the MessageContract however, because I need to put some of the properties in the SOAP header.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this normal behaviour? How do I get a *ResponseClass* return type, when using a MessageContract?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `[MessageContract]` contains more than one `[MessageBodyMember]`, then WCF will return the first one as return value from the service call (`AnimalSpeciesCode` in your case), and all others are returned as `out` or `ref` paraemters.

You can solve this by having only a single `[MessageBodyMember]` in your message contract that encapsulates all items you need to have return, something like this:

```
[DataContract]
class CompoundData
{
    public string AnimalSpeciesCode { get; set; }
    public int VBN { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class ResponseClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public CompoundData Payload { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, the `CompoundData` should be the return value from your service call - containing both elements you need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Marc, that did it. 
I made a generic ResponseWrapper class to encapsulate the return types:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "http://mynamespace.com")]
public class ResponseWrapper<T>
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://mynamespace.com")]
    public T Response
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have defined the returntype of OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate to be

```
ResponseWrapper<ResponseClass> OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate();
```

In my client code this translate to

```
ResponseClass OrderSelfSignedHealthCertificate();
```

Which is what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding answers, unless you've actually found an answer.